# How to get td content vertically aligned?

Tags: bootstrap-4, jhipster

Using Jhipster v5.0.1 and Angular v6.0.0.

**Goal**

I want to vertically align text in my tds.

**Try**

I tried simply to add align-middle into my table:

```
<table class="table table-striped text-center align-middle">
```

Here text-center class works but not align-middle.

**Try 2**

I tried to change directly the style in _tables.scss as following:

```
th,
  td {
   padding: $table-cell-padding;
   vertical-align: middle;
   border-top: $table-border-width solid $table-border-color;
  }
```

Subsequently, I did a yarn start to try to update the styles. However, the changes is not taken into an account.

**Issue**

Can I change directly a class in the table to vertically align things? How a change in the scss can be detected by the app and the browser?

Thanks!

Manuela

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I want to vertically align text in my tds.* then why are you using that class on `<table>` element?

You will have to add the class align-middle to the td-element like below:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="align-middle">middle</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

NOTE: **`<td class="align-middle"> doesn't work when the table class is <table class="table-responsive">`**

Comment: Ok thanks. I wonder whether there would be a simpler way? It seems a little heavy to add this class in all my tds. Thks!